# How can I validate my google map search text box for invalid input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, validation

this is my first question on stackoverflow hope I get tons of answers ;)

I have integrated the google map api to autocomplete my search place textbox and display the selected place on a map on the same page on my travel planner app.

What I want to achieve - If the user enter's invalid value in the search textbox the form should not be submitted.

What I'm doing - I'm using jquery validation plugin for validating other elements on the form. 
In the submit handler I'm calling a function to validate the search textbox. Here is the function :

```
function validateMapSearchInput(searchBoxID)
 {
     var addressField = document.getElementById(searchBoxID);
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

     var search = geocoder.geocode(
                  {'address': addressField.value}, 
                    function(results, status) { 
                       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                       { 
                           var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
                           console.log(addressField.value+" found on Google");
                           console.log("loc : "+loc);
                           return true;
                        } 
                        else {
                           console.log(addressField.value+" not found on Google");
                           return false;
                        } 
                });
        console.log("search: "+search);
        return search;
}
```

And here's where I'm calling it:

```
$('#r_frmAddTrip').validate({
errorClass: "addTripError",
rules:{
    r_tripName:{
        required : true
    },
    r_tripDesc:{
        required : false
    },
    r_tripDestination:{
        required : true
    },
    r_tripType:{
        required: true
    },
    r_startDate:{
        required: true
    },
    r_endDate:{
        required: true,
        compareDates: "#r_startDate"
    }        
},
messages:{
    r_tripName:{
        required: "Please Enter Trip Name."
    },
    r_tripDestination:{
        required : "Please Enter Destination."
    },
    r_tripType:{
        required: "Please select trip type."
    },
    r_startDate:{
        required: "Please select start date."
    },
    r_endDate:{
        required: "Please select return date.",
        compareDates: "Return date should be greater than start date."
    }
},
submitHandler: function() {
    console.log("No add trip validation errors!");
    var searchStatus = validateMapSearchInput('r_tripDestination');
    console.log(searchStatus);
    if(searchStatus){
        addTrip();
        console.log("Trip added");
    }else{
        console.log("TRip not added");
    }        
    return false;
}
});
```

Problem : searchStatus is always undefined.. I have no idea why.. If I could atleast return something I can make this work. I even tried returning strings instead of true/false.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

`geocoder.geocode(...)` is an AJAX call, so returning the result of that method call will give you nothing, instead you need to make use of the callback to perform further actions based on the result.

Something like

```
$('#r_frmAddTrip').validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    validateMapSearchInput('r_tripDestination', form);
  }
});
```

Then

```
function validateMapSearchInput(searchBoxID, form)
{
    var addressField = document.getElementById(searchBoxID);
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode(
        {'address': addressField.value}, 
        function(results, status) { 
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
            {
                var loc = results[0].geometry.location;
                console.log(addressField.value+" found on Google");
                console.log("loc : "+loc);
                form.submit(); // continue with form submission
            } else {
                console.log(addressField.value+" not found on Google");
            } 
        }
    );
}
```

Please note that this is untested, your mileage may vary...

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mxrz/